# Is it possible to approximate irrational by fractions with denominator and numerator odd?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-approximation

Suppose $\alpha$ is a positive irrational, and $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real, are there $m,n$(non-negative integers) such that $$|\alpha-(2m+1)/(2n+1)|<\epsilon/(2n+1)?$$ 
If they exist, are there infinitely many $m,n$?
It seems in this case the Dirichlet approximation theorem can not be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

The formula $|\alpha-(2m+1)/(2n+1)|<\epsilon/(2n+1)$ is equivalent to $\|\alpha m+\frac{\alpha-1}{2}\|<\epsilon/2,$ where $\|x\|$ is a distance from $x$ to  nearest integer. This problem is covered by Minkowski inhomogeneous approximation theorem, see *Cassels, An introduction to diophantine approximation*, Theorem II A (he gives two proofs).

Comment: Minkowski's theorem is a bit of an overkill - having rewritten the inequality, it follows immediately from density of $\alpha m$ modulo $1$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, indeed! Sorry for using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut.